# Cordova: testing alert plugin in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm trying to install and test the [Cordova alert plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs) in the browser.

I have created a demo project and added an Android platform to this project too.

Now, according to the instructions given on the plugin's page, we can test it in browser?

```
Firefox OS Quirks:

Both native-blocking window.alert() and non-blocking navigator.notification.alert() are available.
```

so I tried something like this:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

<script>
        function alertDismissed() {
    // do something
}

window.alert = navigator.notification.alert(
    'You are the winner!',  // message
    alertDismissed,         // callback
    'Game Over',            // title
    'Done'                  // buttonName
);
</script>
```

but when I open the HTML file in firefox, I get no alerts in the browser at all!
Is there something that I'm missing?

EDIT:

I noticed when I remove the document ready function I get the following error: `TypeError: navigator.notification is undefined`

Second Edit:

Now I've changed my code to the following and I get no errors but I don't get any Alerts in the browser either:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
  if (navigator.notification) { // Override default HTML alert with native dialog
      window.alert = function (message) {
          navigator.notification.alert(
              message,    // message
              null,       // callback
              "My Title", // title
              'OK'        // buttonName
          );
      };
  }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, in order for the deviceready to fire you need the cordova.js.

The event listener will not fire inside your laptop/PC's browser because the file does not exist; you will probably get an error inside your console that says cordova.js was not found. That's why you always test by emulating your project, because as soon as you type `cordova emulate android` or `cordova build android` the cordova.js file will be automatically generated inside your platform's www directory and then the event listener will fire. Hope I explained it right :p

Answer (score 0):

First of all check debug if `navigator.notification.alert` is defined, because you redefine native browser `window.alert` by it, therefore it can't be executed

Comment: I get this in the console: eferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: hmm.. Do you use jquery code without adding jquery's file to you source?

Comment: well as I see in your EDIT a TypeError: you try to get `alert` method from `navigator.notification` object which is not defined.  just make a check `if(navigator.notification.alert){window.alert = navigator.notification.alert;}`

Comment: No, unfortunately i still get the same error. I just taken the code snipet from the plugin's page so it should really work. I don't understand why it doesn't!!!!

Comment: furthermore you assign result of a `navigator.notification.alert` to a `window.alert` which is dislogical :) for example you assigning `var getSize = (function(){return Math.floor(Math.random()*100);})();` where your right part is not a function than a result of a function

Comment: just see the difference between `window.alert = navigator.notification.alert;` from docs and your `window.alert = navigator.notification.alert(...);`

Comment: first of all if you try to test in a browser you need to check if cordova's `navigator.notification.alert` is defined in your page, than assign.